# Rewrite GoTo Statements

Tags: c#, goto, code-conversion

I've been given the task of re-writing a program that uses goto statements for the sole purpose of demonstrating how frustrating they can be and I have learned that they are indeed very frustrating. After several hours of flipping through the debugger I am still running into problems, is there anyone who could pseudo code this for me that I could potentially understand it better? Apart from creating if and else statements for each goto I am lost.

```
namespace Assignment_03_Nasty_Code
{
    class Assignment03
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Assignment 03 = " + new Assignment03().Solve());
        }

        public int Solve() 
        {
            int result = 0;
            int upperSearchLimit = 1_000_000; 
            Console.WriteLine("Building list of primes...");
            ArrayList primes = Utils.BuildListOfPrimes(upperSearchLimit);
            Console.WriteLine(" Done.");
            // Step through the odd composite numbers
            for (int i = 19; i < upperSearchLimit; i+= 2) 
            { 
                Label02:
                if (primes.Contains(i)) 
                    goto Label03;
                // Is the number divisible by a prime?
                int j = 0;
                Boolean match = false;
                Label01:
                int tmp;
                int prime = (int)primes[j];
                tmp = i - prime;
                int half = tmp /= 2;
                int squareRoot = (int) Math.Sqrt(half);
                if (tmp != squareRoot * squareRoot) 
                    goto Label04;
                // We got one
                //System.out.println(i + " is a composite that can be written as the sum of a prime and twice a square");
                match = true;
                Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + (int)primes[j] + " + 2 * " + half );
                Label04: // Second goto
                j++;
                if ((int)primes[j] < i) 
                    goto Label01; 
                if (match == false) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No match for " + i);
                    result = i; 
                    break;  
                }
                //goto Label02;
                Label03: // First goto
                int x;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing I'd do would be run the code through a formatter!

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose, then again I suppose the purpose was to teach me to never use a goto statement and well I don't need to be told why after this.

Comment: What he meant was to fix indenting, the "wall of text" is unnecessarily hard as it has multiple problems regarding maintainability, the "goto" statement is just one of those problems. Fix indentation to begin with, then start dealing with goto.

Comment: "That kind of defeats the purpose" - A **formatter** will only fix things like indentation ... this will help you understand what is going on.

Comment: "I suppose the purpose was to teach me to never use a goto statement" - well, Mission accomplished. But I suppose there are more lessons to be learned: 1. Indentation is crucial to readability of code. 2. Don't try to "alter" that code. Understand what it does and then "do it right". ... just to name 2.

Comment: BTW, the commented-out `//goto Label02;` should probably not be commented out, and (I'm not sure if this is a C# language syntax issue) `Label03: ;` would suffice.

Comment: "Label03: ; would suffice" - I guess figuring that out is part of the "lesson" ;) @KenY-N

Comment: I apologize for the formatting, I gave it as it was given to me. It was likely done intentionally for me to fix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have replaced `goto` in your code and that's result

```
public int Solve()
{
    var result = 0;
    var upperSearchLimit = 1_000_000;
    Console.WriteLine("Building list of primes...");
    ArrayList primes = Utils.BuildListOfPrimes(upperSearchLimit);
    Console.WriteLine(" Done.");

    for (var i = 19; i < upperSearchLimit; i += 2)
    {
        if (primes.Contains(i))
        {
            continue;
        }

        var j = 0;
        var match = false;
        do
        {
            int tmp;
            var prime = (int)primes[j];
            tmp = i - prime;
            var half = tmp /= 2;
            var squareRoot = (int)Math.Sqrt(half);
            if (tmp == squareRoot * squareRoot)
            {
                match = true;
                Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + (int)primes[j] + " + 2 * " + half);
            }

            j++;
        } while ((int)primes[j] < i);

        if (match == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No match for " + i);
            result = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: OP was explicit about **not** wanting a "finished code" solution.

Comment: (Did not downvote, though ^^ )

Comment: I was really hoping for an outline of what the code does as opposed to a hard coded answer but this does work thank you. This is much easier to understand though.

Comment: @Fildor Its true,  it is not what I asked for, I wanted someone to pseudo code it for me so I could figure it out myself but I've been using Ubuntu too much and wrote sudo instead so I think people got confused. Also, the question was getting downvoted and I thought I should at least give some credit when someone tries to help me.  That and I don't like to downvote unless it really needs to be.

Comment: @shockemc I didn't mean it *should* be downvoted. It's just here on SO "please give me code" questions are pretty much frowned upon. And your question is not one of those by explicitly asking for an outline, only. So answering it with a completely fixed copy&paste code solution could possibly encourage questions of the first kind. But, well ... the world still turns :)